# looking for a mipmap generator in java

Tags: java, android, class, mipmaps

I need to generate a mip map from an arbitrary image (different formats, not necessarily squared) in java.
Because I don't like to reinvent the wheel I spend some time looking for a  stand alone java class, without any luck.

Does anyone know a simple class solving my problem?
Should run on android ;) .

**notes**:

- I know OpenGL can create MipMaps BUT I needed them outside of any OpenGL context.
- The image is a big one ( 16K x 8K ).
- creating it in OpenGL and exporting it issn't an option because of the size.

Comment: You can't generate them in OpenGL and export them?

Comment: The image is far to big for an android device to handle it ( 16K x 8K ). Wich is part of the reason I need this in the first place :) .

Answer (score 0):

Cant you hand the rendering off to a server farm/ "the cloud"?

Use android only for the real necessary client calculation. Amazon nowadays provides VMs with graficcards.

Comment: No I can't ;) . Its my task to build a smart algorithem instead of just throw raw rendering power at it ;) .  
Also I may need to implement video chat with more than one client in the future so I need the bandwidth for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @Velrok: Is it possible to split the image into smaller parts and compute each tile separately?

Comment: I do the mipmap generation on the server now running my own python implementation. https://github.com/Velrok/PyMipMap .  
  
Doing this on an android device seams to be a bad idea for large images anyway.